# fade multiple images on click with display properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a simple click the color button to change the color of the product image, and I am completely new to javascript but I found this code that allows me to switch between multiple images with multiple buttons, however I want to get them to crossfade when clicked.

For example I made this where there are 2 iPhones, and the button corresponds to the color of the phone (ideally I would like 3+ options)

```js
function showImg( id ) {
    for ( i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        var obj = document.getElementById( "picture" + i );
        if (obj != null)
        obj.className = 'hide';
    }
    
    var obj = document.getElementById( "picture" + id );      
    if (obj != null)
    obj.className = 'show';
    
}
```

```css
.show {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transition: ease-in-out 1s;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
    opacity:0;
    max-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transition: ease-in-out 1s;
}

.btn {
    margin: 20px !important;
}

.black {
    background: #333;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #333, #555) !important; 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #333, #555) !important;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #333, #555) !important; 
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #333, #555) !important;
}

.silver {
    background: #ccc;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #ccc, #fff) !important; 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #ccc, #fff) !important;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #ccc, #fff) !important; 
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #ccc, #fff) !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <img id="picture1" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/515a5LWWpHL._SL1000_.jpg" title="Silver" class="show img-responsive">
                <img id="picture2" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/613bFC-bCvL._SL1500_.jpg" title="Black" class="hide img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <button class="btn silver" onClick="showImg(1);" value="Silver"></button>
                <button class="btn black" onClick="showImg(2);" value="Black"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function showImg( id ) {
    for ( i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        var obj = document.getElementById( "picture" + i );
        if (obj != null)
        obj.className = 'hide';
    }
    
    var obj = document.getElementById( "picture" + id );      
    if (obj != null)
    obj.className = 'show';
    
}
```

```css
.show {
    animation: fade-in 1s ease-in-out forwards;
}
@keyframes fade-in{
     0%{
          opacity:0;
          
       }
    100%{
          opacity:1;
       }
 }
 img{
     position:absolute;
     max-height: 100vh;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
  }
  
.hide {
    animation: fade-out 1s ease-in-out forwards;
}
 @keyframes fade-out{
     0%{
          opacity:1;
       }
    100%{
          opacity:0;
       }
 }
.btn {
    margin: 20px !important;
}

.black {
    background: #333;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #333, #555) !important; 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #333, #555) !important;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #333, #555) !important; 
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #333, #555) !important;
}

.silver {
    background: #ccc;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #ccc, #fff) !important; 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #ccc, #fff) !important;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #ccc, #fff) !important; 
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #ccc, #fff) !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <img id="picture1" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/515a5LWWpHL._SL1000_.jpg" title="Silver" class="hide img-responsive">
                <img id="picture2" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/613bFC-bCvL._SL1500_.jpg" title="Black" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <button class="btn silver" onClick="showImg(1);" value="Silver"></button>
                <button class="btn black" onClick="showImg(2);" value="Black"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That's almost exactly what I was looking for! Except the image disappears before it fades, do you know if there is any way to have it crossfade into each other?

Comment: @CyleHowe I think i know but do you consider using jquery?

Comment: I don't know any jquery, but I'm open to it